# Network descriptive statistics in R

Tags: r, dataframe, networking, dplyr, igraph

Given a random network

```
set.seed(100)    
network_test <- erdos.renyi.game(250, 200, type = "gnm",directed = TRUE, loops = TRUE)

V(network_test)$gender <- sample(c(0:2), 250, replace = TRUE)
V(network_test)$race <- sample(c(1:5), 250, replace = TRUE)
E(network_test)$relation <- sample(c(1:3), 200, replace = TRUE)
```

Is there a (standard) way in `R` to produce a **table of descriptive statistics** summarizing what goes on in the network itself?

I am thinking of the following:

- [No.] Vertexes
- [No.] Edges
- [No.] components
- [No.] Diameter
- [name(top 5)] Vertex per attribute
- [Mean, Min Max, SD, name(top 5)] Degree
- [Mean, Min Max, SD, name(top 5)] Strength
- [Mean, Min Max, SD, name(top 5)] Closeness (considering components separately)
- [Mean, Min Max, SD, name(top 5)] Betweenness (considering components separately)
- [Mean, Min Max, SD, name(top 5)] authority_score (considering components separately)
- [Overall, Min Max, SD] Edge density (considering components separately)
- [Overall, Min Max, SD] Reciprocity (overall and considering components separately)
- [Overall, Min Max, SD] Transitivity (overall and considering components separately)
- [No.] Communities

**I really do not want to re-invent the wheel** - so if there is an established way to do so it would be great to know.